# How to align div horizontally in this case

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="check > <div>hello</div> x3 <div> jello</div> y3 </div>
```

I was expecting css like following to place all item horizontal.

```
 #check {display:inline;}
```

But I get something like this:

```
hello
x3
jello
y3
```

I want something like:`hello x3 jello y3`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply the `inline` style to all of the divs you want on the same line.

Spans might be better suited to your purpose since that's what divs and spans are for.
See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Dtj/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 #check div {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use it for divs inside the container

```
 #check div {display: inline;}
```